# pdsh and command exit code

Tags: exit-status, pdsh

I would like to use `pdsh` to assert that a command successfully run on multiple nodes, if the command fails on any nodes the exit code (from `pdsh`) should be non-zero.

Consider the following examples:

```
$ pdsh -w host1,host2 "exit 0"; echo $?
host1: host1
host2: host2
0
```

```
$ pdsh -w host1,host2 "exit 1"; echo $?
host1: host1: ssh exited with exit code 1
host2: host2: ssh exited with exit code 1
0
```

```
$ pdsh -w host1,host2,host3 "exit 1"; echo $?
host1: host1: ssh exited with exit code 1
host2: host2: ssh exited with exit code 1
host3: host3: ssh exited with exit code 255
0
```

The second example should return a non-zero exit code.

In the third example `host3` does not exist and still the exit code is zero.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pdsh` with its `-S` option.

From the manual:

> `-S`
> Return the largest of the remote command return values.

This would set the `pdsh` utility's own exit-status to the maximum exit-status of any of the commands executed on the remote hosts.

Comment: Thanks, the "return values" throw me off, as I was looking for exit code/status.